# Search in Item2 in List<Tuple>

Tags: c#, list, tuples, contains

I've been struggling.
How do I write this:

```
/* initialization */ 
List<Tuple<string, string, string>> mytuples = new List<Tuple<string, string, string>>();

// pseudocode:
if(mytuples.Contains("hello") in Item2)
{
    Console.Write("Success");
}
```

Comment: Please read [faq] and [ask] before asking a question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
/* initialization */ 

List<Tuple<string, string, string>> mytuples = new List<Tuple<string, string, string>>();


bool containsHello = mytuples.Any(c=>c.Item2.Contains("hello"));

if(containsHello )
{
    Console.Write("Success");
}
```

Comment: Applies to `List<(sting A, string B, string C)>` ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use linq to check it:

```
List<Tuple<string, string, string>> mytuples = new List<Tuple<string, string, string>>();

if(mytuples.Where(t=>t.Item2.Contains("hello")).Any())
    Console.Write("Success");
```

Comment: My answer is faster :), yours will get all items those contains hello and then see if there is any items. mine will stop when it find some match.

Comment: This queries absolutely equivalent.They both stops at first matching

Comment: This is due to lazy evaluation.