# How to Search a String in List<Tuple<string,string>> in C#

Tags: c#, list, tuples

I am having a

```
        List<Tuple<string,string>> tr = new List<Tuple<string,string>>();
        tr.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Test","Add");
        tr.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Welcome","Update");

        foreach (var lst in tr)
         {
             if(lst.Contains("Test"))
              MessageBox.Show("Value Avail");

          }
```

I failed while doing this ,....

Comment: What does "failed" mean?

Comment: what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Your code posted here has a lot of compilation errors. Missing ')' and lst obviously does not contain a definition for Contains. You should post code which can compile and then shows your problem. Konstantin's answer below solves your issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Probably this should work:

```
foreach (var lst in tr)
{        
    if (lst.Item1.Equals("Test"))        
        MessageBox.Show("Value Avail");
}
```

or this

```
if (lst.Item1.Equals("Test") || lst.Item2.Equals("Test"))
```

---

Read [Tuple Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536.aspx); you'll need to access values of the tuple through `Item1` and/or `Item2` properties.

---

And why use Tuple at all? Maybe this is easier:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"Test", "Add"},
    {"Welcome", "Update"}
};

if (dict.ContainsKey("Test"))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Value Avail:\t"+dict["Test"]);
}
```

Comment: Applies to `List<(string A, string B)>` ?

Answer (score 16):

If you'd like to use LINQ:

```
if(tr.Any(t => t.Item1 == "Test" || t.Item2 == "Test"))
    MessageBox.Show("Value Avail");
```

This will also have the benefit of only showing the message box once if the text is found multiple times (if that is what is desired).

Answer (score 2):

```
List<Tuple<string,string>> tr = new List<Tuple<string,string>>();
tr.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Test","Add");
tr.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Welcome","Update");
var index = tr.FindIndex(s=>s.Item1 == "Test" || s.Item2 == "Test");
if(index != -1)
MessageBox.Show("Value Avail");
```

Using FindIndex, you can check the availability and index of element at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

it should be `foreach (var lst in tr)` not lstEvntType and you should test for the tuple's Item1 field instead.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this might help someone else. Here is the method I went with:

```
List<Tuple<string,string>> tr = new List<Tuple<string,string>>();
tr.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Test","Add");
tr.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Welcome","Update");

if(lst.Any(c => c.Item1.Contains("Test")))
    MessageBox.Show("Value Avail");
```

(credit goes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13901400/2352507))

Answer (score 0):

Why are you iterating over lstEvntType  and not tr? You should try this:

```
List<Tuple<string,string>> tr = new List<Tuple<string,string>>();
tr.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Test","Add"));
tr.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Welcome","Update"));
List<Tuple<string,string>>  lstEvntType = new List<Tuple<string,string>>();

    foreach (var lst in tr)
    {
        if(lst.Item1.Equals("Test"))
            MessageBox.Show("Value Avail");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if(lst.Contains("Test"))
```

To

```
 if(lst.Item1.Contains("Test") ||  lst.Item2.Contains("Test"))
```

If tuple has more items, you need to add condition for all items.

If you want to make it common for all tuples, you need to use Reflection (and [the quirky way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196991/get-property-value-from-string-using-reflection-in-c-sharp)).